# How can I set VisibilitySensor to trigger the event only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am using `react-countup` for a count up transition and `react-visibility-sensor` to detect if component is in viewport. Here, I want to count up to 100 only once and not everytime the component is in the viewport. So, I have used the `useState` hook to deactivate the `VisibilitySensor` once the transition ends. But, this code doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

```
const [state, setState] = useState(true);
<CountUp end={1000} duration={5} onEnd= {() => {
  setState(false);
  }} >
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
        <VisibilitySensor active={state} onChange={start} delayedCall>
            <span ref={countUpRef} />
        </VisibilitySensor>
    )}
</CountUp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround for my problem. Setting the start value to 0 for the first time and then making it equal to the end value otherwise.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(true);
<CountUp start={state ? 0 : 1000} end={1000} duration={5} onEnd= {()=> setIsActive(false)} >
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
        <VisibilitySensor onChange={start} delayedCall>
            <span ref={countUpRef} />
        </VisibilitySensor>
    )}
</CountUp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the active state on your onChange event by setting it to false (disable the sensor).

```
const [ active, setActive ] = useState(true);
const [state, setState] = useState(true);

const onChange = () => setActive(false)
<CountUp end={1000} duration={5} onEnd= {() => {
  setState(false);
  }} >
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
        <VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange} active={active} delayedCall>
            <span ref={countUpRef} />
        </VisibilitySensor>
    )}
</CountUp>
```

Comment: I'm using the `state` variable to set active as false. But it seems to not be working.

Comment: cannot tell what your onEnd does, but if you want to just trigger once then u set it in onChange event of VisibilitySensor

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in my code. After the transition has ended, I'm setting `state=false` which is passed to the active prop. But it is not working.

Comment: It is likely because you are wrapping VisibilitySensor in CountUp, which is beyond your control, perhaps you would want to move VisibilitySensor of CountUp.

Comment: I have posted the solution that worked for me. Thanks for your help!